# jquery parent, parents, and closest can't select or step over a section tag

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM structure below:

```
<div class='box'>
    <section id="profile">
        <h1>testuser</h1>
        <div id="following">
            <a class="btn unfollow" style="width: 180px;" rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" href="/users/testuser/unfollow">Unfollow</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then I have a trigger on the response to the link and I have a `$(this)`.  I can confirm that I am at this point in the DOM with some console logging.

Doing a `$(this).parent()` give me the div with the id #following.

However I can't select the #profile or .box using `parents()`.  Doing a `parent().parent()` also gives a nil?

Is there some reason I cannot traverse up the DOM tree over the section tag?

Comment: Figured out the problem.  The part I didn't show was that the #following div was replaced in an earlier step. Since I am deleting the whole parent I just took that part out and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$.closest()`:

```
$(this).closest(".box");
```

Of course this problem seems a bit suspicious. I was able to successfully access `.box` (and `#profile`) with `$.parents` without problem:

```
$(".box").on("click", "a.btn.unfollow", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents(".box").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uranit/edit#javascript,html

We'd need to see how you went about selecting these elements.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine to me: `alert($("a").parent().parent().attr("id"))`​ returns "profile". See: http://jsfiddle.net/TZawQ/